# How to find missing values of Catagorical/character type in Rstudio

Tags: r

Facing problem to detect missing value for character/catagorical type values. As we can use "is.na" for numerical or integer type values, is there any keyword to find for character type values?

I am looking for a solution for this problem.

Comment: Its the same. Use `is.na`

Comment: is.na can't detect character type values in dataset

Comment: `is.na` CAN detect `NA` values in a dataset. eg `is.na(data.frame(a = c("a", NA, "b")))` should work. Or do you mean you have empty strings? Include a small dataset in your question to indicate what youi have and also what you want

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I mean values which are missing is empty in dataset. For example "first", "second", " ", " third"

Comment: You can use `nzchar` to identify strings which have at least one character in them, so `!nzchar(c("first", "second", "", " third"))` returns `FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE`. An empty string is not the same thing as `NA`. In your example, your 'empty' string isn't even empty, but has a space in it. If you want to identify strings that are empty _or_ have only spaces then you can use regex, e.g. - `grepl('^\\s*$', your_string_variable)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. "!nzchar(mydata$class)" this is working to find missing values for character type values in my dataset. How to remove or insert values in missing values?